how to obtain a pop-up or system alert when my timer ends in Django
I have a task-timer app, the timer model has an attribute "end" that takes in timefield by generics.createAPIview. I want to add a feature using signals such that, when the timers end time reaches current time, I want a pop up or a flash message or system notification.
models.py
class timer(models.Model):
   
    name=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    start=models.TimeField(default=datetime.now())
    end=models.TimeField(default=(datetime.now()+timedelta(minutes=45)))
  
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name 

views.py

class TimerCreateView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = timer.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TimerSerilaizer
    
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Handle GET requests to display the countdown timer
        event = timer.objects.first()  # Retrieve the first Timer object
        if event:
            now = timezone.now()  # Get the current time (offset-aware)
            today_end_naive = datetime.combine(now.date(), event.end)  
            
            # Make today_end offset-aware by adding the current timezone
            today_end = timezone.make_aware(today_end_naive, timezone.get_current_timezone())

            if today_end < now:
                # If the end time has already passed today, use the next occurrence (tomorrow)
                today_end = today_end + timedelta(days=1)

            time_remaining = today_end - now  # Calculate time remaining
            total_seconds = time_remaining.total_seconds()
            hours = int(total_seconds // 3600)
            minutes = int((total_seconds % 3600) // 60)
            seconds = int(total_seconds % 60)

            data = {
                'name': event.name,
                'hours': hours,
                'minutes': minutes,
                'seconds': seconds
            }
       
        return render(request, 'myapp.html', {'data': data})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Handle POST requests to create a new timer
        response = super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)
        
        # After creating the timer, call the get method to display the countdown
        return self.get(request, *args, **kwargs)

I tried using signals, celery and channels. I expected the pop-up while browsing other website or any other window, or a system alert when the end time reached current time. Instead only the browser page, had a count down timer.
Is there any better solution instead of signals, like plyer python or pywin?

If I understand you correctly, to do what you want, you need to use the webpush API. Read about it and how to configure it on the client and server.
